# Get columns if no data in query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, php-5.3, symfony-3.4

I want to get the columns selected in query if no data are returned

```
 $sql = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare('
                SELECT
                    DATE_FORMAT(cus.period, "%Y") as ANNEE,
                    DATE_FORMAT(cus.period, "%m") as MOIS,
                    c.name AS PAYS,
                    co.id AS ORIGINE_ID,
                    co.name AS ORIGINE,
                FROM customs AS cus
                WHERE cp.product in (503)
                GROUP BY ANNEE, MOIS, PRODUCT, co.id , c.id
                ORDER BY ANNEE, MOIS, CAMPAGNE, PRODUCT, co.id, c.name;'
        );
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll();
```

I no data the result is an empty array, but I want in case that no data result should be an array like

`$result = [
     'ANNEE', 'MOIS', 'PAYS', 'ORIGINE_ID', 'ORIGINE'

]`

Comment: Even if data *is* returned, it doesn't include column names as the first row.  Why do you need this?  What are you trying to accomplish?  You could perhaps add a static row to your array after executing the query.  Or include a `UNION` in the query which first selects static values for the column names.  But why?  It seems like whatever you want to do there's likely a better way to do it.

Comment: @David, the idea is that I create the csv based on this query, and I have about 20 differents queries. Now if I have data I create the csv with columns on first row and values on next, but if I don't have data I need to create the csv only with one row, and this row will be all column name's.

Answer (score 1):

`getConnection()` in Doctrine returns the PDO it wraps which means we can use [`getColumnMeta()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) to get the column names:

```
$stmt = $sql->execute();
$columnNames = array();

foreach(range(0, $stmt->columnCount() - 1) as $index) {
    $columnNames[] = $stmt->getColumnMeta($index)['name'];
}
```

`$columnNames` can then be added to your `$result`